# dropwizard get on demand jdbi connection

Tags: dropwizard, jdbi

I have a simple CRUD application with backend code in dropwizard. The entire app  just comprises of simple resource classes and crud operations except one case where some business logic is involved.

I am trying to extract this into a service instead of putting it in the resource class itself. But for that my service would need an ondemand jdbi connection to access data and do its thing.

All my connect strings and config values are in YML file. Since this app would be  running on different servers with different yml files, I dont want to hardcode the yml file name in order to read it again, to get the connect strings and do it that way.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry I am missing the question. Do you want to have a way of different configuration for different servers? Wouldn't your connection string be the same for each server always? Do you use DI with dropwizard or just dropwizard alone?

Comment: Yes. the connectstring would be same but it is in the yml file. So I need to read the file in the service I am trying to create. I was able to achieve this by using ConfigFactory but for that I had to hardcode the config file name which I dont want, as it would change from env to env. Does that help? I am not using DI since this was just a CRUD app and never felt the need to.

Comment: Still relevant? I was on holiday. You might have a few options. I changed my configuration to have only 1 yaml file, and have multiple configurations (staging, production, local) to be run in. The configurations are then defined in normal properties files. You can read them using plain java. Better though I think for you would to construct a datasource factory from your yaml and inject this directly. You then don't read the configuration, you just obtain the connection from the factory.

Answer (score 0):

Can you detect what environment you are on?

If so, can you do something like ${environment}.yml?

There is Configuration project on apache which might help.

Otherwise, is it a case of in dev you want to run

`java -jar app.jar server dev.yml`
and in prod you want to run `java -jar app.jar server prod.yml`? I imagine you have separate daemons in each environment. So, those environment's will pick up the right configuration, if you've configured them that way.

Otherwise, if the property names are the same, but their values differ, and you pick up the right yml in the right environment, things should work.

If I haven't addressed your question, can you please elaborate your problem a little more?